# Registration to be configured in ASP.NET Core 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

Currently in my ASP.NET Web API (older version), I have the following code in `Startup.cs`:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register(context =>
{
    var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
    // ...
    return new HttpClient(handler);
}).SingleInstance().Keyed<HttpClient>(0);
```

I need to migrate this API to an ASP.NET Core 8 solution.

Since there is no `Startup.cs` class and also no extension method as `builder.Register`, where should I write this code?

Comment: There's no `ContainerBuilder` in any .NET Core version. That's an AutoFac class. Are you asking how to migrate old AutoFac code? Check the docs of the [Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/9.0.0#readme-body-tab) package.

Comment: _"ASP.NET Core 8 Web API (older version)"_ ASP.Net Core 8 is (currently) the latest version. What do you mean by "older version"?

Comment: You _can_ have a `class Startup` in ASP.NET Core 8 - the whole "top-level code" thing is an opt-in/opt-out setting when creating a new empty project in VS - you can 100% use a `class Startup` today in both upgraded and new projects. (and I've configured my VS to opt-out of top-level code entirely, blegh!)

Comment: Based on your scenario,  register your `HttpClient` within the dependency injection system using `builder.Services.AddHttpClient` in your Program.cs file. This method takes your service interface and implementation, allowing for configuration of the HttpClient's base address and message handler, while also ensuring a single instance is created as in your previous code

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will fix your issue i think.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services
   .AddHttpClient("ClientName")
   .AddHttpMessageHandler<YourCustomHandler>()
   .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
```

**YourCustomHandler .cs**

```
public class YourCustomHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : DelegatingHandler(innerHandler)
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // TODO Do your things before send it.

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override HttpResponseMessage Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { 
        // TODO Sync one.
        return base.Send(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```